# Why is one an Object and one an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, doctrine, codeigniter-2

I have the following two queries:

```
$query = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery("select u from ORM\Dynasties2\Characters u WHERE u.whichFamily = $whichfamily AND (u.deathDate = 0 OR u.deathDate IS NULL) ");
```

and

```
$query = $this -> doctrine -> em -> createQuery ("SELECT a, b.msgText, b.fromUser, b.timeStamp, b.importance, b.msgType FROM ORM\Dynasties2\Maillinks a JOIN a.msgId b");
```

The first query returns an object.

```
array(9) { 
  [0]=> object(stdClass)#108 (18) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=> string(25) "ORM\Dynasties2\Characters" 
    ["id"]=> int(67) 
    (etc)
```

The second query returns an array.

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> array(6) { 
    [0]=> string(24) "ORM\Dynasties2\Maillinks"
    ["msgText"]=> string(24) "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"  
    (etc)
```

Why does the second one return an array?

Is there a simple way to convert it into an object?

(using doctrine2 and codeigniter2)

Edit:

If I change the second query like so:

```
$query = $this -> doctrine -> em -> createQuery ("SELECT a FROM ORM\Dynasties2\Maillinks a JOIN a.msgId b");
```

then the output is an object.  So I've partly answered my question - however, the above code does not return the data that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (if the relationship is defined properly, it should return and object):

```
SELECT a, b FROM ORM\Dynasties2\Maillinks a JOIN a.msgId b
```

Comment: Thanks, I posted a followup question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255941/nested-objects-mixed-results-from-dql-select